# Pandas: sum all rows with the same month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, columnsorting

Say I have the following data:

```
| student      | performance | competititon | month   |
|--------------|-------------|--------------|---------|
| Aardvark     | 11          | A            | 2019-01 |
| Aardvark     | 13          | B            | 2019-01 |
| Jason Derulo | 11          | A            | 2019-01 |
| Jason Derulo | 15          | B            | 2019-01 |
| Jason Derulo | 22          | C            | 2019-02 |
| JP Saxe      | 11          | A            | 2019-01 |
| JP Saxe      | 23          | B            | 2019-01 |
| JP Saxe      | 32          | C            | 2019-02 |
```

I want the following result:

```
| student      | aggregate performance | month   |
|--------------|-----------------------|---------|
| Aardvark     | 24                    | 2019-01 |
| Jason Derulo | 26                    | 2019-01 |
| Jason Derulo | 22                    | 2019-02 |
| JP Saxe      | 34                    | 2019-01 |
| JP Saxe      | 32                    | 2019-02 |
```

In short, I want the sum of the performance column, irregardless of competition, for each month, into a new list.

I've tried things like `where` and `groupby` and `sum` but I can't seem to quite get what I want.

Comment: `df.groupby(["student","month"])["aggregate performance"].agg(["sum"]).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df.groupby(['month', 'student'])[['performance']].sum().reset_index()
```